# Sorting an array by returning 1 or 0 or -1 if it returns these values how the sort function can decide which one to put first

Tags: javascript

I don't understand the logic of sorting an array by returning 1 or 0 or -1 if it returns these values how the sort function can decide which one to put first

Example Let say we have an array

```js
const newArray = [5.55, 4.3, 3.4, 1.8, 2.5];
const modifiedArray = newArray.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a > b) {
    return 1;
  } else if (a === b) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return -1;
  }
});
console.log(modifiedArray);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (a,b) is a compare function which we pass in sort.
Consider the following example:

```
let numbers = [0, 1 , 2, 3, 10, 20, 30 ];
numbers.sort();
console.log(numbers);

The output is:
[ 0, 1, 10, 2, 20, 3, 30 ]
```

So to fix the above issue we pass (a,b) for sorting.

If compare(a,b) is less than zero, the sort() method sorts a to a lower index than b. In other words, a will come first.
If compare(a,b) is greater than zero, the sort() method sort b to a lower index than a, i.e., b will come first.
If compare(a,b) returns zero, the sort() method considers a equals b and leaves their positions unchanged.

If you want to know more about sort in js in details :
https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-array-sort/

Answer (score 0):

The [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) documentation states it like this:

- If your compare function returns -1 then it places a before b.
- If it returns 1 then it places b before a.
- If it returns 0 then the order remains unchanged.

By the way, the compare function does not have to return exactly -1 or 1 but only values that are smaller or greater than 0. So it would be possible to sort an array in ascending order like this:

```
var sortedArray = [1,0,5].sort((a,b) => a-b);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

> If compareFunction(a, b) returns less than 0, sort a to an index lower than b (i.e. a comes first).
>
> If compareFunction(a, b) returns 0, leave a and b unchanged with
> respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all different
> elements. Note: the ECMAScript standard only started guaranteeing this
> behavior in 2019, thus, older browsers may not respect this.
>
> If compareFunction(a, b) returns greater than 0, sort b to an index
> lower than a (i.e. b comes first).

if you put log inside your `modifiedArray()` function,
you can see that the same number is compared again but with other numbers.

You can also read about sort algorithms like "quick sort" and etc.